# Speed: Named Shared Memory vs Memory Mapped File vs Normal Memory

Tags: c++, windows, sql-server-2008, memory

Let's say I have a server, where clients who connect are constantly updating their inventory.

I could simply save the changes in to the database after an item has been updated, or I could update the whole inventory after the client leaves the session.

If I go with the first approach, with my current specs, I can't process all those at the same time. If I go for the second, and my application for some reason dies, the updates are never stored in the database.

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

I can only come up with two solutions (both would imply checksums):

1. Have a secondary application running, which simply creates a named shared memory. The main application will use this memory for the inventory of all the clients, and if it my application dies, then secondary application will keep alive the shared memory, and therefore the data, which can be saved once the main application is re-started.
2. Map each client to a file, ie user1.dat, user2.dat, like the shared memory. However, won't this slow my program? or is it fast as the named shared memory? (If I understand correctly, it should be as fast) (**this is the one in my top list right now**).
3. **UPDATE** After the helpful comments, here's hopefully a better idea: Create another thread, have a file for each client, and instantly update it after every item change. Once the user leaves, only then the whole inventory would be stored in the database as a single transaction. Meaning all the updates take place, or none. If the server crashes, or shuts down, I just have to run it again. No memory mapped file anymore, and of course I will flush the file after every update, and make sure the section I've updated has been written properly ie having **Atomic Commit.** I'm not entirely sure if this will speed up things, since both the database & storing the update in each file will at the end of the day, use the hard drive.

To be more specific about the second approach:

Is there a guaranty, in windows at least, that the following 3 approaches will be as fast in both write/read? **If there's ANY KIND of delay**,I need to know.

As far as I understand, **even the file mapping approach will instantly update the memory**, but not the file itself (which is fine).

```
// normal memory accesss
int *normal_address =            (int*)0x10203040;
*normal_address = 6;             //write: 0.00002sec (for example)
int get_value = *normal_address; //read: 0.000001sec (for example)

// named shared memory
int *normal_address =            (int*)0x10203040;
*normal_address = 6;             //write: 0.00002sec (for example)
int get_value = *normal_address; //read: 0.000001sec (for example)

// memory mapped file
int *normal_address =            (int*)0x10203040;
*normal_address = 6;             //write: 0.00002sec (for example)
int get_value = *normal_address; //read: 0.000001sec (for example)
```

**NOTES:**

My application is written using C++ and windows API. Both approaches (memory mapped file and named shared memory) use these functions:

```
CreateFileMapping

OpenFileMapping
MapViewOfFile
```

- The main application would be updated in a daily basis, so it can potentially end up with a nullptr or something that. The source code is a bit old and will be updated by multiple persons.
- The secondary application would be created once, and never updated unless it's needed. Therefore there's no reason to believe that if the code is well written, no bug should occur in the future to make it crash.

**THOUGHTS (ignore if needed):**

Perhaps the secondary application could make backups of the data without syncronization: first retrieve the checksum, then get the whole inventory. If the checksum doesn't match, then it tries to do it again.

Perhaps another alternative would be to make the secondary application the one who actually handles the items.

4. Everytime a client updates an item, the update would be sent directly to the second application, which would handle the update, and then store the update into the database once the client leaves. Since this application is really small, and it won't change, it's very simple to ensure it won't die. The main application however, will change constantly, which is the reason why it can end up with a null pointer being used by mistake or something like that, and suddendly die.

Comment: what if the *machine* crashes? the updates won't be stored.

Comment: It strikes me you are worrying about relative speeds of operations on different types of memory, but you need to be worrying about fault tolerance.

Comment: Wrong approach.  The standard solution is to use message queuing with a transactional queue.  Makes the system resilient to crashes and powerloss, the message stays in the queue until you remove it after updating the dbase.  Micro-optimizing is not useful, it does not have to be faster than the network and the dbase.

Comment: If an application crashes, it may well do so in a way that corrupts contents of the shared memory. You basically need transactions of some kind. And if you try to hack that together, you are well on your way to re-inventing databases (probably poorly).

Comment: Yes use a input buffer/queue. The flow from the buffer can be controlled nicely, and the application only interfaces with the queue. Just concentrate on that interface.

Comment: KarolyHorvath You are right, this is the only case where the data wouldn't be saved with the file mapping approach. But I think I can live with that. @Peter I'm worried about both things. But having limited resources, I can't have transactions in the database for each item, otherwise it dies. It's a game server, that's why speed matters to me equally. A delay in the server (ie moving an item) would be reflected in the User Experience.

Comment: @hyde yes you are right, that's why I would have checksums to make sure the data wasn't corrupted. Perhaps I could have a file mapping approach, and a secondary application making backups of that mapped memory. On a restart, it would use both things to properly reconstruct the inventory of the user, and if it can't (which would be rare) , I would at least get a notification about it, and would contact the user.

Comment: "If I go with the first approach, with my current specs, I can't process all those at the same time", how do you know this, anyway? Why don't you use an existing database (SQL or nosql, there are plenty with different performance characteristics) as the "secondary application"? Rolling your own "DB" of any kind for production purposes is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @hyde I'm using SQL Server 2008. It can't handle all the item updates fast enough, there's delays. I don't want to have delays.